# How to get row number in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm making an tracking app, and i want to show the user on which place he/she is. For this I thaught of ordering by 'totalkm' desc and then get the row number. The problem is i don`t know how to do this, as i'm fairly new to the Database world.

I tried something like this:

```
WITH mytable AS {
    SET @row_number = 0; 
    SELECT (@row_number := @row_number +1) AS num, user,totalkm 
FROM profile ORDER BY  totalkm DESC ; } 
SELECT num
     FROM  mytable WHERE user = "bogdan9832";
```

But i get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mytable AS {
>       SET @row_number = 0' at line 1

From what i understood, there is no support for WITH in mysql. Can someone show me an alternative?

Comment: You have to use variables. Have a look [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following query for the same:-

First declare the variable as:-

```
SET @row_number = 0;
```

Then use this query:-

```
SELECT (@row_number:= @row_number + 1) AS ROW_NUMBER, OTHER_COLS
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT num, user, totalkm
FROM (

SELECT (
@row_number := @row_number +1
) AS num, user, totalkm
FROM profile
ORDER BY totalkm DESC
) AS a
WHERE user =  "bogdan9832"

Answer (score 0):

Using sub queries but only a single SQL statement:-

```
SELECT num
FROM
(
    SELECT (@row_number := @row_number +1) AS num, user, totalkm 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT banner.*
        FROM profile
        ORDER BY  totalkm DESC
    ) profile
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) sub0
) sub0
WHERE user = "bogdan9832"
```